# Defining restricted subset of Storable for type match

Tags: haskell

I am getting error for the code below - I suspect it has to do with the type signature of `dispatch` function which returns a `Vector` of type `Storable a`. What is the simple way to update `dispatch` function type signature to do only `Int32` and `CChar` in type signature:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.Vector.Storable as SV
import Foreign.C.Types (CChar)
import GHC.Int (Int32)

data AList = I {-# UNPACK #-} !(SV.Vector Int32)
              | S {-# UNPACK #-} !(SV.Vector CChar)


dispatch :: (Storable a) => AList -> SV.Vector a
dispatch (I x) = x
dispatch (S x) = x
```

Error in ghci 7.4.1:

```
    test.hs:11:18:
    Couldn't match type `CChar' with `Int32'
    Expected type: Vector a
      Actual type: Vector Int32
    In the expression: x
    In an equation for `dispatch': dispatch (I x) = x
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I am asking this question assuming my error diagnosis is correct. If my diagnosis is incorrect, I will appreciate pointers on how to fix the error above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type signature

```
dispatch :: (Storable a) => AList -> SV.Vector a
```

says "give me an `AList`, and I'll give you an `SV.Vector a` for *any* `a` you want, so long as it's an instance of `Storable`". That's not right! For any given value, there's only *one* `a` you can supply, and **you** choose it, not the calling code. The problem might be easier to see if you explicitly add the quantifier:

```
dispatch :: forall a. (Storable a) => AList -> SV.Vector a
```

What you really want to say is "give me an `AList`, and I'l give you an `SV.Vector a` for *some* `a` that I choose, but I promise it'll be an instance of `Storable`". For this, we need an **existential type:**

```
data SomeSVVector = forall a. (Storable a) => SomeSVVector (SV.Vector a)

dispatch :: AList -> SomeSVVector
dispatch (I x) = SomeSVVector x
dispatch (S x) = SomeSVVector x
```

(You'll need `{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}` for this.)

This gives `SomeVVector` the type:

```
SomeVVector :: (Storable a) => SV.Vector a -> SomeVVector
```

You can then take the `SV.Vector` out of the result of `dispatch` with `case dispatch x of SomeSVVector vec -> ...`. However, this probably isn't all that useful: since the existential can contain a vector with elements of *any* instance of `Storable`, the *only* operations you'll be able to perform on the data inside are those offered by the `Storable` class. If you want something that user code can analyse and "dispatch" on the type of, you'll need a tagged union — which is exactly what your `AList` type already is.

If you do want to go down the existential route, then I would suggest defining your own typeclass as a subclass of `Storable` that contains all the operations you might want to perform on the values inside. At the very least, you'll probably want to add `Integral` to `SomeSVVector`'s constraint.

---

As you mentioned in the comments, if you don't mind an `AList` of `Int32`s and an `AList` of `CChar`s having different types, you can use a GADT:

```
data AList a where
  I :: {-# UNPACK #-} !(SV.Vector Int32) -> AList Int32
  S :: {-# UNPACK #-} !(SV.Vector CChar) -> AList CChar

dispatch :: AList a -> SV.Vector a
dispatch (I x) = x
dispatch (S x) = x
```

Here, `AList` is essentially a version of `SV.Vector` that only works on certain element types. However, `dispatch` isn't really that useful — there's no real way to "get back in" to an `AList` after you take it out with `dispatch`, because the type unification GADT pattern-matching offers only works with *explicit* pattern-matching; you can't tell that the result of `dispatch` is either an `SV.Vector Int32` or an `SV.Vector CChar`. Something like

```
dispatch :: (SV.Vector Int32 -> r) -> (SV.Vector CChar -> r) -> AList a -> r
```

would work, but that's equivalent to (and more awkward than) pattern-matching on your original tagged union version.

I don't think there's a reasonable way to define a useful `dispatch`; I would suggest using explicit pattern-matching on your original `AList` definition instead.

Comment: thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for. I know what I wrote wasn't right. Now, I have learnt about exitential type better :) Eventually, I will be doing dispatch based on case to convert to another type. Which is why I have tagged union for AList.

Comment: just realized GADT could be another way to do it. Basically, dispatch could have a type signature: (Storable a) => AList (SV.Vector a) -> SV.Vector a. After defining (AList a) using GADT. I just tried an example, and it seems to do the trick of matching types. If you think this works, I will appreciate it if you could edit your answer above with GADT alternative as well. A sample code here: http://hpaste.org/57584

Comment: Unfortunately, it probably doesn't do what you want; I've expanded my answer with an explanation. By the way, as shown in my answer, the `Storable` constraint on `dispatch` doesn't do anything, and you can parametrise `AList` directly on the element type rather than the type of the vector.